# Fastest way to find equation of hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have 4 points $i=1,2,3,4$ in 4 dimensional euclidean space $(x_i,y_i,z_i,w_i)$. If I want to find the equation for the plane through these four points, I can just solve the linear system. However, I need to do this alot, so I was wondering, is there a formula I can use that is faster?

I need the derivatives of this plane, so I need the $a,b,c$ in $ax+by+cz+d=w$

Comment: When you say you need a faster method, do you need to do this manually? Or do you need to write a computer program that can solve this efficiently?

Comment: Computer program

Comment: Like you said, it's just a linear system. There are tons of free programs to solve them, starting with Octave, but also with WA online
http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Matrices.html

Comment: I have matlab, but isnt it faster to use a direct formula for the equation of a plane through 4 points?

Comment: The equation is  a $5\times 5$ determinant (embedding the Euclidean space in projective space).

Comment: Your main options are Gaussian elimination, a generalized cross-product (equivalent to the determinant @Bernard mentions—requires computing five $4\times4$ determinants) or SVD. For such a small matrix, the latter likely doesn’t offer much in performance over the other two methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as stated, is exactly equivalent to finding a right nullvector to a $4 \times 5$ matrix. I think Gaussian elimination (GE) really is basically the only good way to do that programmatically.

Other particulars of what you *actually* need could suggest other problems that might have better algorithms or implementation strategies. Since this is a math forum I'll focus on algorithmic improvements (post to one of the programming sites for potential implementation improvements).

---

An example of the main potential for improvement I see is if you do many computations with the same three points but varying fourth point. The relevant row operations you use in GE to row reduce the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} p_0 & 1 \\ p_1 & 1 \\ p_2 & 1 \\ p_3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
(where each $p_i$ is a row vector of four numbers) can be gathered together to produce a matrix $A$ such that
$$ A \begin{pmatrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ p_2 \end{pmatrix} $$
is in row reduced echelon form. For simplicity, I will assume the first three columns are pivots, so that $A$ is the inverse of the top-left $3 \times 3$ block. In this case, we have
$$ \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
 \begin{pmatrix} p_0 & -1 \\ p_1 & -1 \\ p_2 & -1 \\ p_3 & -1 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & q_0 & r_0
\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & q_1 & r_1
\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & q_2 & r_2
\\ p_{30} & p_{31} &p_{32} & p_{33} & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
If you save the $q_i$'s and the $r_i$'s, it's easy to quickly finish the row reduction. Or, you could just solve the matrix symbolically to get a formula for your hyperplane in terms of $p_3$.

---

The other possibility for algorithmic improvement is if the $p_i$'s are special in some fashion, so that the equation can be simplified using vector algebra or matrix algebra.